# How can I speed up the page load of plots created in Bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh, interactive

After I run my code, the page opens up and for 13 seconds a blank page shows up, and after that, the expected plots.

Is there a way to speed this up? (13 seconds, user wise is sadly too long)

The code produces 44 plots, in two columns(2n loop), differ by parameter (1st loop) and then differ by tool name (3 rd loop)

Also if bokeh, isnt the right tool for this, would happily open to hear a way to plot interactive plots, preferably with python

This is the code:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv("LUSU.csv",parse_dates=['PM_START_DATE'], date_parser=dateparse)

df.head()
print("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
x = df['PM_START_DATE']
y = df['TASK_VALUE']
tool=df['ENTITY']
tool_list=df['ENTITY'].unique()
param_list=df['PARAMETER'].unique()
#
print("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
colors = itertools.cycle(Spectral11)
output_file('LUSU.html', mode="cdn")
for i in range(0,44,2):
    row = []
    for _ in range(2):
        p = figure(title=param_list[i], x_axis_label='date', y_axis_label='chart value', x_axis_type="datetime", toolbar_location="below")
        for j in range(len(tool_list)):
            df1=((df['PARAMETER']==param_list[i] )& (df['ENTITY']==tool_list[j] ))
            source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x.loc[df1], y=y.loc[df1], tool=tool.loc[df1]))
            p.line(x='x', y='y',legend='tool', source=source)
            p.scatter(x='x', y='y',legend='tool',size=10,color=next(colors), source=source)
        p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Entity", "@tool"), ("Chart Value", "@y{%0.2f}"), ("Date", "@x{%F}")], formatters={"x": "datetime", "y": 'printf'}))
        #p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days=["%m/%d/%Y"])
        p.legend.location = "top_right"
        p.legend.click_policy = "mute"
        row.append(p)
        i = i + 1
    grid.append(row)

fig=layout(grid)
reset_output()

show(fig)
```

Comment: Is the script still iterating in the for loop or it is stuck in the "show" function when the page is blank? Could you check it? If the iteration is the problem you may use some [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or multithreading python module

Comment: Anyway I reckon bokeh is not prepared to work with so many plots. Besides, if many axis share some range, I am afraid that panning and zooming is going to be almost imposible. Let me know if you get this working faster because I am really interested

Comment: Ah! If you finally use multiprocessing module take into account [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#bokeh-object-ids). You should use this environment variable `BOKEH_SIMPLE_IDS=no`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use webGL to speed it up.
This allows glyphs to render via the GPU.

```
figure(title=param_list[i], x_axis_label='date', y_axis_label='chart value', x_axis_type="datetime", toolbar_location="below", output_backend="webgl")
```

More information: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/webgl.html.

Further reading about Bokeh performance issues with a lot of plots: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6294.

Comment: hi, i tried this, the output is that not all graphs are being plotted, and no change in time is seen